# Can Python's Tkinter show both text and image in a Button widget?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, toolbar

For practice, I am using Python's Tkinter to copy/recreate the "Options" section of another software's GUI. This is my model GUI:

[image]

At this juncture, I have coded as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import random
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Options(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        random_numbers = lambda: [random.random() for i in range(4)]
        text_font_icon = r"D:\Dropbox\coding\python\experiments\6 - tkinter\icons\icon_mail.gif"

        labelframe_general     = tk.LabelFrame(parent, text="General")
        labelframe_general.pack()

        tk.Label(labelframe_general, text="Startup tab", justify=tk.LEFT).grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W)
        ttk.OptionMenu(labelframe_general, tk.StringVar(), random_numbers()[0], *random_numbers()).grid(column=1, row=0)

        tk.Label(labelframe_general, text="Episode display format", justify=tk.LEFT).grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W)
        ttk.OptionMenu(labelframe_general, tk.StringVar(), random_numbers()[0], *random_numbers()).grid(column=1, row=1)

        tk.Label(labelframe_general, text="Number of banner images to\ndownload per series", justify=tk.LEFT).grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=tk.W)
        ttk.OptionMenu(labelframe_general, tk.StringVar(), random_numbers()[0], *random_numbers()).grid(column=1, row=2)

        tk.Checkbutton(labelframe_general, text="Automatically scroll episode list to bottom", variable=tk.StringVar()).grid(column=0, row=3, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.W)
        tk.Checkbutton(labelframe_general, text='Move "The" to the end of series name', variable=tk.StringVar()).grid(column=0, row=4, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.W)
        tk.Checkbutton(labelframe_general, text="Close epCheck with the <Esc> key", variable=tk.StringVar()).grid(column=0, row=5, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.W)

        _photo = tk.PhotoImage(file=text_font_icon)
        b = ttk.Button(labelframe_general, text="List & Overview font (right-click for default", image=_photo)
        b.image = _photo
        b.grid(sticky=tk.NSEW, columnspan=2)


class Gui(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        Options(self)

        self.bind('<Escape>', lambda event: self.destroy())

gui = Gui()
gui.mainloop()[![enter image description here][2]][2]
```

The above produces this:

[image]

My problem lies only with ttk.Button (all the other widgets are behaving as I expect them to).

The Button only shows the icon, but does not state the text "List & Overview font". My questions:

1. Why has the text disappeared from the the Button when an image is used?
2. Can Tkinter display an icon together with, or next to, texts in Buttons (like in the model GUI above)?
3. Are Tkinter 'toolbars' or widgets able to display icons together with text, or am I constrained to choose text-only Buttons and Image-only buttons?

I have experimented with Menubutton and tested code from other sources, but to no avail. Would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a value for `compound` option of [ttk.Button](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Button.html).

> If you provide both image and text options, the compound option
>   specifies the position of the image relative to the text. The value
>   may be tk.TOP (image above text), tk.BOTTOM (image below text),
>   tk.LEFT (image to the left of the text), or tk.RIGHT (image to the
>   right of the text).
>
> **When you provide both image and text options but don't specify a**
>   **compound option, the image will appear and the text will not.**

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Also: 1) Is there any way to 'pad' the image from the text, so that there is some space between them? And 2) Can you text-align/justify the image/text _within_ the Button widget?

Comment: @anonnoir As far as I know, no you can not do any of those. Only option to add a padding is adding extra spaces but that may not reliable because of fonts etc.